# Can I push (>1) specific matching branches to their origins simultaneously?

Tags: git, branch, push

Is there a way to push more than one branch (but not all branches) to their respective origins with a single command?

Something to the tune of: <sub><sup>(Warning, code is untested)</sup></sub>

```sh
git push origin branch1 branch2
```

to push `branch1` to its remote and `branch2` to *its* remote.

I **do not want** to push any branches not specifically included.

Comment: That works fine: naming the two local branches as "refspecs" is exactly equivalent to writing `branch1:branch1 branch2:branch2` at that point.  This will non-force-update the two branches on the remote (`origin`), creating them if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** As of Git version 1.8.4.2, I just tested and I think the behavior you are looking for exists exactly how you stated. I just did this flow:

```sh
mkdir a
cd a && git init && touch README.md && git add . && git commit -m "Initial commit" && cd ..
git clone ./a b
cd b && git branch a && git branch b && git branch c
git push origin a b c
```

> ```
> Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
> To ~/git-test/./a
>  * [new branch]      a -> a
>  * [new branch]      b -> b
>  * [new branch]      c -> c
> ```

### Original

The syntax of `git push origin branch1 branch2` is saying push my *local* branch named `branch1` to a remote repository named `origin` and call the branch I'm pushing onto repo origin `branch2`.

To do what you want, try adding a colon between each: The first being the local name and the second being the remote name.

```
git push origin branch1:branch1 branch2:branch2
```

Comment: Could I leave off the post-colon names? `git push origin branch1: branch2:`

Comment: @Michael, please see the update I just made to my answer... I KNOW the colon separator works on older versions, but perhaps I just was wrong the whole time about the naming :D